# Shell running as sudo when called manually, not when called from cron (sudoers)

Tags: bash, cron, sudoers

Firstly, if this has been answered somewhere else please let me know and I'll delete this question. Other folks seem to be better at searching this site than I am.

I have a script that has been added to my sudoers file, which will run as sudo when called manually from the command line (the script is always called from inside another program, so I mean I call the parent script) without prompting me for my password. The child script changes permissions to ensure that the parent can manipulate the files as needed. However, when the parent is called from cron, the child script isn't running, or at least isn't running properly (I made the stdout write to a log to make sure of what I was seeing). See below for script details

from cron:

```
bash * * * * * '/path/to/script/foo.sh' &> /dev/null
```

call inside parent script:

```
source /path/to/childScript/bar.sh $dirToManipulate >> $LOG
```

child script in full:

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    find "$1" -type d -exec chmod -vR 777 {} \;
    find "$1" -type f -exec chmod -vR 777 {} \;
else
    echo "No folders/files given"
fi
```

Like I said above, if I manually call the parent script from terminal (`bash /path/to/script/foo.sh`) then the child script does what it's supposed to and modifies the permissions of the files in the specified directory, but when the parent is called from cron (`bash * * * * * '/path/to/script/foo.sh' &> /dev/null`) the child script fails to modify the permissions of the files in the specified directory.

Inside SUDOERS file:

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/childScript/bar.sh
```

Comment: where are the `$dirToManipulate` and `$LOG` vars being set so that they are visible from your cron entry?  Until you get a working system, not advisble to redirect ouput to `/dev/null`. Try `> /path/to/log/dir/dirFixerScript.log.$(\%Y-\%m-\%d.\%H\%M\%S)` for a short period of time (given that your running this every minute). There are better ways to do this, but depends on your OS etc. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter `$dirToManipulate` and `$LOG` are defined at the top of `/path/to/script/foo.sh`. Will outputting the cron execution to `> /path/to/log/dir/dirFixerScript.log.$(\%Y-\%m-\%d.\%H\%M\%S)` yield different results than outputting to the log from inside the called script?

Comment: different results: yes, very likely. There may be errors at the cron and `sudo` level that would not appear in the inner scripts log file. Basically for this sort of question, we hope you'll just run a simple test for  yourself and be guided by differences that you see. While still developing your solution, it helps to add `echo "top of foo.sh" .... at end ... echo "end of foo.sh"` etc for all scripts OR use `set -x` at the top of the script to see a debug trace and understand what is being executed, including values for your variables. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! This is what happens when the developers won't do things that need doing so that it's left up to a dilettante such as me.

Comment: "source" != "sudo". Outside of that, it's not entirely clear how `sudo` even has a role here, since none of the code calls it...

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better option that I could find, I switched from using my user cron to the root cron. I do not recommend this to those who come after me.